# how to write custom PreAuthorize Annotation and Intercepter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Not sure if this is a duplicated
 question or not,

For some reason I want to have my own annotation to apply spring authorization. Something like this:

```
@AdminAccess({AdminRoles.ENROLLMENT, AdminRole.REPORT})
public myController() {...}
```

And

```
public @interface AdminAccess {
    AdminRoles[] value() default {AdminRoles.LOGIN};
}
```

Actually I want to replace this annotation with Spring PreAuthorize annotation.

Thanks,